# How can I delete my MailGun Sending Domain?

Tags: subdomain, mailgun

I had a sending domain created in my MailGun account, which was verified etc. However I wanted to record the process or creating & verifying the domain for our clients, so I deleted the domain.

However when I tried to recreate the same domain, I got the error "Failed to create Domain".

The domain is now there, but seems to be incomplete. If I go into domain settings, it now says "There was an error loading your data, please refresh to try again", and I'm unable to delete it.

I realise I can probably create a completely separate domain, but I would like to either get this one working, or removed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you delete and try again if need be. Here are the steps to delete:

[Deleting A Domain](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203637190-How-Do-I-Add-or-Delete-a-Domain-)

What if you no longer use a domain or if there is a typo in the domain name?  We'll show you below how you can eliminate the domain from the account.

Inside the Mailgun Control Panel (options displayed down the left-hand side on a dark column), use the following instructions:

- Click on Sending on the left-hand side of your Mailgun dashboard.
- On the resulting page, click the domain you wish to delete.
- Click on Domain Settings on the left-hand side of your Mailgun dashboard.
- Towards the bottom of the resulting page, there will be a button that allows you to delete the domain from the account.

Comment: That's all well and good, but on the account I'm trying to modify, there is no Delete option, link, button, checkmark, or anything. So the above copy & paste from mailgun is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this one too, because you'd expect that after clicking on the domain name you'd be presented with some options and not just a graph. What clicking the domain actually does is switch you to the "overview" tab on the left, which is pointless for trying to delete the domain.

Scroll down to the bottom of the "Sending" tab on the left until you see "Domain Settings". Click that, verify the domain you want to delete is selected in the top right drop down menu, and scroll to the bottom and click on "Delete" in the advanced section.